# PHPmyadmin installation problem

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

I can't install phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 10.04 it says

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   phpmyadmin: Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `php5-mcrypt` to satisfy the dependency:

`apt-get install phpmyadmin php5-mcrypt`